# ld: warning: unexpected srelocation type 9 while building in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi I get around 7000 such warnings in the link stage of building my app for distribution

```
ld: warning: unexpected srelocation type 9
```

Any idea what this is and how I can fix it?

EDIT:

These warnings come during the link stage of 'armv7' only when building for distribution, and I also get the following warning

```
warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current ARCHS = "armv6").
```

I have checked that armv7 is included in valid architectures" for both debug and distribution configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Please check the following settings in your apps :

In the Info.plist. Check for "Required device capabilities" info, and look the data inside. You should have 2 items (NSArray) : armv6 and armv7

Answer (score 1):

Try setting "Enable Linking With Shared Libraries" under Build Settings to NO

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround for me was to build in XCode 4.2.   It appears something in the .a file is not compatible.   I was using LLVM-GCC which I thought would fix it, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it from "Link Binary With Libraries" is OK