# Warning: ld: warning: unexpected srelocation type 9 while building on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using XCode Version 3.2.5. I am developing an application where if I build the application on the device, I get the following warning

```
ld: warning: unexpected srelocation type 9
```

I have followed the steps given in the following link

[unexpected srelocation type 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823220/ld-warning-unexpected-srelocation-type-9-while-building-in-xcode)

I have tried to follow all the step in the one where we have to set the following code in the info.plist file

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>armv6</string>
<string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

But, still, I dont know why I am getting this particular warning. Please Help.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. i have resolved that for debug mode.. But warnings still comes for distribution mode. Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you used some libraries which was build with Xcode4 or later version.So if you want to stop these warning
,you should build your app using Xcode4 too.